# Redirect with parameters in tomcat7

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7, context.xml, server.xml

I'm trying to redirect to my application in tomcat7,
I want a link to my app as: http://my_IP/newpath/

I've created `ROOT.xml` in `/conf/Catalina/localhost` with :

```
<Context
 deployOnStartup="true"
 docBase="/path/in/linux/tomcat7/webapps/MyAppName/"
 path="/newpath"
 debug="0"
 reloadable="true"
/>
```

(In MyAppName folder there is index.html file.)

**Question:** 
my app needs to be called for correct use:

`../MyAppName/index.html#/main/` or `../MyAppName/#/main/`

I've tried, without success:

- calling `webapps/MyAppName.war`
- adding in `ROOT.xml` something like:
  `.../MyAppName/index.html#/main/` and
  `.../MyAppName/index.html%23/main/`

I quest there is a problem with this '#' sign, 
as well I read that I should have redirect to sub-folders (?)
Any suggestions?
Thank You in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution, not very elegant, but working:

in /path/in/linux/tomcat/conf/server.xml I've added content as above

in /MyAppName/ I've added new file:
go.html with content of index html
in original index.html I've added, in head section:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://my_IP/newpath/go.html#/main/" />
```

I know that redirect in `<meta>` in head is not advised.

All functionality and links are working in my app.